# How can I pass TRUE from javascript to a C# script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have:

```
function SelectSubTopics() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Administration/Tests/SelectSubTopics",
        data: { DataSource: $('#DataSource').val(),
            testID: $('#TestID').val(),
            showAll: True
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#TID').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to pass a value of True through to the C# program which accepts a bool for the showALL parameter but I am getting a javascript error saying  "SCRIPT5009: 'True' is undefined "   Is there some special way to pass true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lower case: `true` - that's all. If the case is important, use a string: `"True"`

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is case-sensitive which means `true` is not `True`. Also note that `showAll` in your server-side script is not `bool` it's a `string`.